# Libgdx detect wrong keycode while using macOS

Tags: libgdx

i'm new in libgdx and i'm trying to learn to use this framework. I'm used to code on ubuntu but recently I purchased a macbook in order to dev on it.

While my code is working perfectly on both OS. There is only one bug that remains on my program.

When I try to make my character move "on a top down view rpg style", It seems that Libgdx detect my keyboard as a QWERTY, while I can ensure that there is 0 Keyboard layout/mapping installed as a qwerty. Only a AZERTY one. MacOs is also configured as a French system.

Is there a other special way for "apple" machines so that your sprites moves on a screen in libgdx ? Until now I did like this :

```
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.Z))
        player.setY(player.getY() + GameSettings.playerSpeed * dt);
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S))
        player.setY(player.getY() - GameSettings.playerSpeed * dt);
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D))
        player.setX(player.getX() + GameSettings.playerSpeed * dt);
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.Q))
        player.setX(player.getX() - GameSettings.playerSpeed * dt);
```

In the end when my "z" key is pressed nothing happen (on macOS only) but if I press "w" it works just fine.

Thanks for the futur explanations !

Answer (score 0):

If you create an InputAdapter/InputProcessor you can detect what keycodes are being called when you press each key.

[Here's the link to it on the wiki.](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling)

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter () {
@Override
public boolean keyDown (int keycode) {
  System.out.println("Key Down Event, keycode: "+keycode);
  System.out.println("Z keycode: "+Input.Keys.Z);
  return true; // return true to indicate the event was handled
  }
});
```